# How to make autofac resolve constructor with parameters in real time?

Tags: c#, autofac

Easy example for understanding what i mean:

```
public interface IWarrior
{
    string GetName();
}

public class HumanWarrior : IWarrior
{
    string _name;
    public HumanWarrior(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _name;
    }
}

public class  AnimalWarrior : IWarrior
{
    string _name;
    public AnimalWarrior(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "animal" + _name;
    }
}
```

In my code i use it like:

```
    ...code
    string warriorName = "Glark";
    WarriorService warriorService = new WarriorService(new HumanWarrior(warriorName));
   ...code
```

I know how i can use Autofac to resolve IWarrior if nested classes have empty constructors; But what if i need to create example of IWarrior, that needs "name" parameter, and i cant configure value of this parameter in Autofac settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it like that, that's not the point of an IOC container like Autofac.

What I would do is create a `public string Name {get; set;}` property or a function `public void Init(string name) { ... }`

Edit:
This is how I would build it

```
public class HumanWarrior : IWarrior
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Or something like this:

```
    public class HumanWarrior : IWarrior
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public void Init(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

With the interface like this:

```
public interface IWarrior
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i cant understand your solution. Where do i need to put this property or method?